# Solving equation for sum of 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let's say I have a basic equation (here a linear combination):
$$ax_1 + bx_2=y$$

Is there any way to get the value of the sum $x_1+x_2$ if $a$, $b$ and $y$ is known?

Comment: As a simple (counter)example, take $a=1$, $b=-1$ and $y=0$. Is there anything you can say on $x_1+y_2$?

Comment: In the special case where $a = b$, then $x_1+x_2 = \frac{y}{a}$

Comment: Well, there are infinitely many solutions for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no further restrictions on $x_1$ and $x_2$, then we cannot *in general* (see *Lacklub*s comment below) say anything about $x_1+x_2$, as the system is [underdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system), i.e., there are more variables than equations.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Some systems of equations which are undetermined can still have conclusions about *particular combinations* of variables, just not every single one. In particular the equation $2x + 2y = 4$ is undetermined, but we *can* conclude that $x + y = 2$

Comment: @Lacklub Thank you, I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any additional information, no.

For example, there are lots of pairs of numbers that differ by $1$, but their sum could be anything. Consider the pairs (0,1), (10,11), (1000, 1001).